# Powershell deleting more files than it should, bug?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm using the following snippet of code in a powershell script to clean up files that we no longer need, however this appears to delete everything (thank God for backups...) and not just those modified older than $limit, can anyone explain this behavior?

```
param (
    [int]$daystokeep = 548 # default to 18 months 
)

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1 * $daystokeep) # 18 months

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.ModifyTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: `ModifyTime` isn't a property... so that's always returning `$true` since it's comparing to `$null`.  You're looking for `LastWriteTime`.  Voting to close since this is basically a typo question.

Comment: To prevent this kind of silent ignoring of nonexistent properties, the use of `Set-StrictMode` comes highly recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileInfo` objects have no `ModifyTime` property, so your comparison basically evaluates to:

```
$null -lt $limit
```

which is always `$true`.

Change the property name to `LastWriteTime`:

```
$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit
```